# memtest86+ doesn't show up in grub

Tags: linux, boot, grub

According to my package manager memtest is installed and both `memtest68+.elf` and `memtest86+.bin` are in my boot partition yet grub doesn't give me the option to boot to them. Is there anyway to add the option?

Comment: did you run `memtest-setup`?

Comment: @Bratchley nope and I just tried. It said command not found. I'm running Linux Mint which comes with it pre-installed. It shows on my VM fine running the exact same version. My best guess is my system is UEFI based and the VM is BIOS but I don't know.

Comment: UEFI shouldn't affect anything. Even if it did, you'd still have an entry in grub. Does `/etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+` or something similar exist?

Comment: @Bratchley that exact file exists.

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu system where I am [try taking a look at this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu)

Comment: @Bratchley So my guess seems to be right https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1024980#p1024980 if you look at the second to last post on that page it seems to be a UEFI thing.

Comment: @Scoopta I don't know if Mint's GRUB does some trickery to hide it, but the GRUB entry does show on my (Debian) UEFI system (although it doesn't work)

Comment: @outlyer well it shows on my laptop and VM which are mint under BIOS but my gaming PC which is UEFI doesn't show it even though the entry file is there for it in /etc/grub.d so I'm assuming mint does hide it if you're on UEFI. It works fine on my BIOS systems but unfortunately I need to run it on my UEFI one.